# Eclipse java coin toss

Tags: java

I need help in order for the output to also show the toss count since now it only shows the tosses showing heads. Tails heads tails and so on until it gets three heads but it is supposed to also show the toss count.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Coinrolling {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random(); 
        boolean noConsecutive = true;
        int flipCount = 0;
        int randomFlip;


        while (noConsecutive) {

            randomFlip = rand.nextInt(2) + 1;

            if (randomFlip == 1) { 
                System.out.println("heads"); 
                flipCount++;
            }else { 
                System.out.println("tail"); 
                flipCount= 0;
            }
            if (flipCount == 3) {
                noConsecutive = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have an easier time getting help if you tag the language you're writing in

Comment: how would do it manually on a paper. You would have a counter whose value you would be incrementing with each toss. Now you can have a similar counter and with each count print the counter or at last when game is over then print the final count at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `tossCount` variable in the same way you already have `flipCount`. You can also simplify the `while` loop condition by checking `flipCount`:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int flipCount = 0;
int tossCount = 0;
while (flipCount != 3) {
    int randomFlip = rand.nextInt(2) + 1;
    tossCount++;
    if (randomFlip == 1) {
        System.out.println("heads");
        flipCount++;
    } else {
        System.out.println("tail");
        flipCount = 0;
    }
}
System.out.print("tossed " + tossCount + " times");
```

Comment: i tried using this code but the toss count seems to always appear as 3 no matter what.

Comment: The chance that you get exactly 3 tosses is `0.5^3 = 1/8`. I just got 24 tosses.